# Merge two arrays and keep additional fields (difference between array's objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I can't find a clean way to merge two arrays and keep additional fields, the difference between array's objects.

```js
  const currentForm = [
    {
      name: "username",
      type: "string",
      info: "enter username",
      value: "test"
    },
    {
      name: "password",
      type: "aes",
      info: "enter password",
      value: "pass"
    }
  ];

  const newForm = [
    {
      name: "username",
      type: "string",
      info: "enter username"
    }
  ];
```

After merging I want this array :

```js
  const currentForm = [
    {
      name: "username",
      type: "string",
      info: "enter username",
      value: "test"
    }
  ];
```

I achieved this with a complex function but I think it can be achieved easily with es6 syntax.

Working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/merged-arrays-18m1t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I don't understand. Your result just seems to be an array containing the original `currentForm[0]`. I don't see any merging.

Comment: What happend to the password object?

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: I want it to work for any currentForm / newForm array

Comment: @Reyno as the new form don't include a password field, it does not appear in the merged array

Comment: What I'm currently missing is the "key" of each "form" object. How you can tell an object is equals to the other? from the "name" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `name` is the unique key of each object we can do the following.

- First we merge all the fields with the same name with
  [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

  - We use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the same field in the other array.
  - We merge both objects using [destructering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- Then we filter out the fields we no longer have with
  [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

  - To see if an object is present in the new array we use [array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which returns a boolean as result that we can pass back to the filter method.

```js
const currentForm = [
  {
    name: "username",
    type: "string",
    info: "enter username",
    value: "test"
  },
  {
    name: "password",
    type: "aes",
    info: "enter password",
    value: "pass"
  }
];

const newForm = [
  {
    name: "username",
    type: "string",
    info: "enter username"
  }
];

const mergeForms = (firstForm, secondForm) => {
  // Merge all fields
  const mergedFields = firstForm.map((obj) => ({...obj, ...secondForm.find(({ name }) => obj.name === name)}));
  // Filter out fields we no longer have
  const fieldsToKeep = mergedFields.filter((obj) => newForm.some(({ name }) => obj.name === name));
  // Return fields
  return fieldsToKeep;
};

// Merge 2 forms
const mergedForm = mergeForms(currentForm, newForm);

console.log(mergedForm);
```

Comment: Thanks ! That's much cleaner ! 
I forgot to mention that I also want to keep fields that are present in newForm and not in currentForm. 
To handle this I've added a step to your solution : https://codesandbox.io/s/merged-arrays-forked-llje4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to merge each object of the first array with the object at the same position in the other array:

```
currentForm.map((obj, i) => Object.assign({}, obj, newForm[i]));
```